# WPF: How to put a tree view inside the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

How do I place the treeview class inside the datagrid, I already have a datagrid that has been populated but now I want a tree view for each row, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to style the template of the `DataGridRow` to show a `TreeView`.

Take a look at this [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/WPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa) that shows how to achieve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great article @III